# Pasting Today's date along with new range of data when macro is run

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that uses a vba code that when a button is clicked, it copies names from one sheet and paste it below the last cell of another. The code works, but I also want to be able to paste the current date in the corresponding column when those names are populated. I thought about making another column with Excel's Today() function, but that ends up pasting the formula instead of the value. Is there a better way to just paste the date into a range of cells?

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Site Specific")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Manual Time Collection")
'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column B employee name
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  
'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column B employee name
'Offset property moves down 1 row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("B2:B" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
  wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
wsCopy.Range("G2:G" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
  wsDest.Range("G" & lDestLastRow)
wsCopy.Range("H2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
  wsDest.Range("E" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

Sheet to copy from [sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA8fS.png)

Sheet to paste in [sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikgya.png)

Comment: You can write the date to an entire range in one go, e.g. `Range("A1:A10").Value = Date`.

Comment: Thanks! what about writing it to that newly pasted range once the macro is run? I tried wsDest.Range("E" & lDestLastRow).Value = Date, which represents pasting it into the first blank row

Comment: Perhaps `Dim rowCount As Long`, `RowCount = wsCopy.Range("B2:B" & lCopyLastRow).Rows.Count`, `wsDest.Range("E" & lDestLastRow).Resize(RowCount).Value = Date`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!